# Unable to add asm schematic in Spartacus 3.2

Tags: spartacus-storefront

When installing asm with schematics in Spartacus 3.2, I have the following error :

`ng add @spartacus/asm`

`Skipping installation: Package already installed`
`schematics_2.addPackageJsonDependenciesForLibrary is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be multiple reasons for this:

- you might have an older version of `@spartacus/schematics` installed:

  - Please check in your `package.json` if you are have `@spartacus/schematics` on the same version as the `@spartacus/core`.
  - if so, please check is `node_modules/@spartacus/schematics/package.json` *actually* on the same version as the `@spartacus/core`.
- please make sure you are installing the 3.2 version of ASM by running `ng add @spartacus/asm@3.2`

Comment: Yes it works now, I fixed following problems :
- Angular cli has been downgraded to 10
- schematics was not declared in dependencies

Comment: Great, thank you for following up.
And yes, you need angular 10 CLI for Spartacus 3.x