# The asm feature module is not launched

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I manually added it in SpartacusFeaturesModule but I don't have the top banner :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    AsmFeatureModule
  ]
})
  }
export class SpartacusFeaturesModule { }
```

At debug, the asm parameter is detected, and the addUi() method is launched (in AsmEnabler).
However the layer is still not displayed.

```
  protected addUi(): void {
    this.featureModules
      .resolveFeature('asm')
      .subscribe(() => this.launchDialogService.launch(LAUNCH_CALLER.ASM));
```

Comment: If the issue its not related to asm=true, can you provide more info about the installation steps you tried?  Did you add the asm library dependency to your project?  How did you implement the AsmFeatureModule?

Comment: I added "@spartacus/asm": "^3.2.0" in package.json and launched npm install.

Comment: Have you tried installing asm via schematics instead? (link to 3.x doc) :
https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/3.x/schematics/#installing-additional-spartacus-libraries

Comment: Yes and I have an error, I created this other ticket for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68999787/unable-to-add-asm-schematic-in-spartacus-3-2

Comment: I managed to install via Schematics but this still does not work.
At debug, I can overall see the rendering being called but no more precision why there is no ASM.

Comment: Can you please provide steps to reproduce the issue from an out of the box Spartacus installation?

Comment: See one of the answers below for the ootb installations that are known to work.

Comment: It works with OOTB Spartacus. In fact 3.4 has been installed. I don't know what from custom code prevent it from being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If everything is properly installed, you need to add the url parameter `asm=true` for the asm header to show.

for example `http://localhost:4200/electronics-spa/en/USD/?asm=true`

Answer (score 0):

ASM UI should appear (using `asm=true` query string param to the url) by installing out of the box Spartacus with default installer options (with Angular 10.2):

```
ng new myapp --style=scss --routing false
cd myapp
ng add @spartacus/schematics@^3.2 --baseUrl {mybackendurl} --baseSite=electronics-spa
```

You can also try and unselect ASM from the installer options and add it afterwards with:

```
ng add @spartacus/asm@^3.2
```

ASM should also show up as expected by adding `asm=true` query string param to the URL.